# Irrespective of mentioning int as return type when I return string, I am still not getting error! why is that?

Tags: python, function, return, void

What is the use of mentioning a return type?

```
def func() -> int:
    print("H")
    return "Harith"

x = func()
print(x)
```

Comment: Who ever promised that typing was _enforced_?

Comment: If you want the accuracy of your hints to be checked, use a type checker. Python itself doesn't do it; they're just notes so a separate tool you run can do checking.

Comment: The `-> int` is just a typing *annotation*. The annotation is for you (as the coder) and also for the IDE, so that it can aid you better and make you think twice about accessing a `str` method on the result, for example. But as noted, it does not explicitly prohibit you from doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal, as from the Python documentation for [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

> **Note:** The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

Of course, it would only be reasonable to follow the type hints.